# Facebook login onlogin callback triggered twice

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook login on a website.
Code used :

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,email,user_birthday,status_update,user_status,user_hometown,user_location" onlogin="checkFBLoginStatus();">Sign in with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

When the user is already logged in to facebook  and click on the button generated by this code , the function specified in the onlogin even is triggered twice.

in fbinit i have

```
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth: true
```

and function checkFBLoginStatus contains just an alert statement

Comment: Are you using `status : true` in your FB.init? Have you signed to `auth.login` event? Put the code of your `checkFBLoginStatus();` function here.

Comment: i had edited my question to provide some more details.I am not using auth.login just the onlogin event as mentioned in facebook login button code

Comment: But `checkFBLoginStatus();` is a personalized function, isn't? It's necessary to check how you are calling the user's FB status...

Comment: Same issue, did anyone ever find a solution to this?